# Why doesn't my opamp work?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to display the voltage at the probe, varying the Vout1 from 0 to 67mV and I expect the voltage to be 0.1V to 0.5,  but my simulation stops way before 0.5V. I have checked the calculations and they are correct, also tried with an ideal opamp and it works.

How can I solve this, any ideas?

[image]

EDIT:

1. It's supposed to display at the probe a voltage of 100mV when the Vout is 0 and a voltage of 0.2 mV when the vout is 67mV.
2. It controls the gain of the Vout.
   Actually it works when I use the ideal opamp, my question is what kind of opamp should I use to get my results..

Comment: (1) What is the circuit supposed to do? (2) Why is R14 connecting the two non-inverting inputs (pin 6)? This looks wrong. Please [edit] your question to explain.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer - yet. This is just to tidy up the schematic and maybe help you see what you have done wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7IAys.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn.*

You need to edit your question to explain:

1. What is the circuit supposed to do?
2. What is R14 supposed to do?